# URL rewrite and sitemap with inactive categories

Tags: url-rewrite, sitemaps

I have 2 stores in the same installation (multistore)

I have 1 root category and 3 subcategories.

In store1 I have active subcategory1 and subcategory2.

In store2 I have active subcategory1 and subcategory3.

It's everything ok, except that in store1's url rewrites I'm seeing url's from subcategory3 (not active at this store) and the same happens with the sitemap.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the following file 
`app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/seo/tree.phtml` file in your theme.

Add an if condition just after the foreach loop which checks for activeness of the $_item.

```
<?php $_items = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<?php if($_items->getSize()): ?>
    <ul class="sitemap">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
          <?php if( $_item->is_active ) : ?> 
            <li class="level-<?php echo $this->getLevel($_item) ?>" <?php echo $this->getLevel($_item)?'style="padding-left:' . $this->getLevel($_item, 2) . '0px;"':'' ?>><a href="<?php echo $this->getItemUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $_item->name ?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="note-msg">
        <?php echo $this->__('There are no %s available.', $this->getItemsTitle()); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif ?>
```

For the issue with the active/inactive categories you could try this

Copy `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php` to your local folder and edit the function `_refreshCategoryRewrites`

```
$specificCatID = $category->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($specificCatID);

if ($category->getIsActive()) {
.. the actual code of the function
    }
```

Not sure if that works and I haven´t tested it but might be worth a try

Comment: it fix the sitemap trouble but not the url rewrite, thanks!

Comment: I will look into it more. I thought if its only one category simply deleting it would be enough

Comment: yeah but I want to open more stores and i need to fix it before open anymore.

Comment: Updated it and you could give it a try

Comment: Did you give it a try?